# DB2OLEDB v5 and SQL Server 2016

Tags: linked-server, sql-server-2016

I connect to an AS400 database using DB2OLEDB v5 as a linked server from SQL Server 2016--but Binary to Character will not translate.  All binary fields on the AS400 database are returned as hex on the SQL Server.  Has anyone had success using this type of linked server from SQL Server 2016? The provider string below is the same one I used successfully on SQL Server 2012.  I really appreciate any help that can be provided.  Here is my Provider string:

```
exec master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'JDE'
 , @srvproduct = N'DB2OLEDB'
 , @provider = N'DB2OLEDB'
 , @datasrc = N'192.168.x.x'
 , @provstr = N'Provider=DB2OLEDB;
 User ID=########;
Password=########;
Initial Catalog=S06822B5;
Network Transport Library=TCPIP;
Host CCSID=37;
PC Code Page=1252;
Network Address=192.168.x.x;
 Network Port=446;
Package Collection=QGPL;
Default Schema=CRDDTA;
Process Binary as Character=True;
Units of Work=RUW;
DBMS Platform=DB2/AS400;
Use Early Metadata=False;
 Defer Prepare=False;
DateTime As Char=False;
Rowset Cache Size=0;
Datetime As Date=False;
AutoCommit=True;
Authentication=Server;
Decimal As Numeric=False;
 Derive Parameters=True;
LoadBalancing=False;
Persist Security Info=False;
Cache Authentication=False;
Mode=Read;
Connection Pooling=False;'
 , @catalog = N'S06822B5' 
/* For security reasons the linked server remote logins password is changed with ######## */
```

and

```
 exec master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname = N'JDE'
 , @useself = N'False'
 , @locallogin = null
 , @rmtuser = N'connect'
 , @rmtpassword = '########'
```

Comment: This might be helpful: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/FindPost1002649.aspx

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately this article is 7 years old and my issue is with SQL Server 2016.  I have DB2OLEDB converting binary to character on SQL Server 2005, 2008 and 2012--just not able to get the interface to work with 2016.

Comment: True, I just thought the 32bit/64bit driver issue might still be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: for correct connection string and SQL server version use DB2OLEDBV6_x64.msi which part of SQL SERVER 2016 SP2 Feature Pack